# Transferring a Windows 10 Install to Ubuntu Virtual Box

Tags: dual-boot, virtualbox, windows-10, license

I recently dual-booted my laptop to run Ubuntu and Windows 10.

Is it possible to move my entire Windows 10 installation into a Virtual Box instance in Ubuntu? Are there licensing issues with transferring the image?

My end goal is to have Ubuntu be the only system on my computer with Windows 10 running occasionally but only from the Virtual Box.

Comment: I would think there would licensing issues based on the fact that Microsoft says that their license is for one machine but it would be best to ask their customer care as they would be in the best position to define whether a "virtualbox" is seen as a physical device!

Comment: I don't see an angle here that involves Ubuntu support. I see a Windows-migrate-to-VM question, and I see a Windows license question.